# Clarification of definition of quotient group - Does $Na, a \in G$ mean "cosets of $N$ in $G$"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition

The definition of quotient group from [mathworld.wolfram.com](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuotientGroup.html) is:

> For a group $G$ and a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$, the quotient group of $N$ in $G$, written $G/N$ and read "G modulo N", is the set of cosets of $N$ in $G$.

I don't understand the part "set of cosets of $N$  in  $G$". Later it continues:

> The elements of $G/N$ are written  $Na$.

From this, I conclude that the expression "set of cosets of $N$ in $G$" means the set of cosets which have elements $Na, a \in G$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation "$Na$" means exactly "the coset of $a$ in $G/N$."

So $G/N$ is exactly the collection of cosets $\{Na\mid a\in G\}$. Note that this set notation does not irredundantly list the cosets.

I don't think "the set of cosets **which have** elements $Na, a \in G$" is a valid way of saying it. The cosets don't *have* $Na$ as elements, each coset *is* an $Na$.